# how can I get the content of my JTextPane?

Tags: java, jtextpane

Hy everyone! I'm stuck in a little problem.

I need some help or an idea, something...I have some words in a `JTextPane` and I want to read them one by one.

I know I have to do it with StringTokenizer or with this

`Element doc=textPane.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement()`,

Thank you for any idea, or help. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: If by "words" you mean text strings separated by spaces, you can just use `split` method.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text from a `JTextPane` with [`getText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#getText%28%29):

```
String text = txtpane.getText();
```

Then, if you want to get each word, you could split around each *non*-word character using a regex:

```
String[] words = text.split("\\W"); // "\\W" is \W, which is non-word characters
```

If you just want to do it based on whitespace, you could use:

```
String[] words = text.split("\\s"); // "\\s" is \s, which is whitespace
```

Then, to "read them one by one," iterate over each element in the array:

```
String text = txtpane.getText();
String[] words  text.split("\\W");
// or: String[] words = txtpane.getText().split("\\W")
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much alex23 and WChargin

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you found this answer helpful, please consider upvoting it (gray up arrow) or marking it as the accepted answer if it completely solved your problem (green checkmark outline).

Comment: your posts really helped me